# django form getting value from previous instance?

Tags: python, django, forms

any ideas why this is happening?

```
(Pdb) import copy

(Pdb) tmpForm=copy.copy(form1)
(Pdb) form1
<cms.forms.MainFeaturedForm object at 0x7f05a0493350>
(Pdb) tmpForm
<cms.forms.MainFeaturedForm object at 0x7f05a054e950>
```

copying form1 to tmpForm (and making sure they're on different memory addresses) to make sure this behaviour is not happening because form1 is being changed

```
(Pdb) v1=form1.save(commit=False)
(Pdb) v1.position
```

as can be seen above, v1.position == None right after a form1.save(commit=False)

```
(Pdb) v1.image_type=2
(Pdb) v1.Article=article
(Pdb) v1.section=33
(Pdb) v1.save()
(Pdb) v1.position
55L
```

here I set some values and saved it
the save() function changes v1 position to 55 (that's expected)

```
(Pdb) v2=tmpForm.save(commit=False)
(Pdb) v2.position
55L
```

but now, after I saved v1, v2 (a completly new instance) has a position setted to the same one that was set on v1 (not expected)

---

in case it helps, here's the save() function of this object (class Featured):

```
def save(self):
    if self.Article:
        try:
            featured = Featured.objects.get(Article=self.Article, section=self.section)
            self.hiddenID = featured.hiddenID
            if self.position == None:
                if featured.position == None:
                    self.position = 55
                else:
                    self.position = featured.position

            super(Featured, self).save(force_insert=False, force_update=True)
        except Featured.DoesNotExist:
            self.hiddenID = None
            super(Featured, self).save(force_insert=True, force_update=False)
    else:
        self.hiddenID = None
        super(Featured, self).save(force_insert=True, force_update=False)
```

Comment: What makes you think the memory address is significant? I can't think of any reason why it would be. You don't show the important code, which is what `form1` actually is and how it is instantiated.

Comment: I was just making sure it wasn't the same object

form1 = MainFeaturedForm(request.POST, prefix = "f1")

    class MainFeaturedForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Featured
        fields = ('text1', 'text2')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **copy.deepcopy**() rather than copy.copy (wild guess: probably it's sharing the data dict instance ...).

> but now, after I saved v1, v2 (a completly new instance) has a
>   position setted to the same one that was set on v1 (not expected)

That is incorrect. A modelform instance sets self.instance in **init** and then only works on that. If you copy the reference to form.instance and then modify it outside the form, it will of course be reflected on form.instance.

deepcopy vs. copy:

```
In [1]: import copy

In [2]: a={'foo':'bar'}

In [3]: b={'x': a}

In [4]: bb=copy.copy(b)

In [5]: b['x']['foo']
Out[5]: 'bar'

In [6]: b['x']['foo'] = 'test'

In [8]: bb['x']['foo']
Out[8]: 'test'

In [9]: bbb=copy.deepcopy(b)

In [10]: bbb['x']['foo'] = 'y'

In [11]: bb['x']['foo']
Out[11]: 'test'

In [12]: b['x']['foo']
Out[12]: 'test'

In [13]: bbb['x']['foo']
Out[13]: 'y'
```

The thing is that copy will just copy a value, and the references it contains are preserved. deepcopy() copies a value and all the values it contains.

Comment: it worked with copy.deepcopy() as jpic suggested... but I still don't understand why this problem is happening in the first place.
After I do form1.save(commit=False), how is form1 changed by what I do to the object created by it?

Comment: Because the references contained by form1 are kept. With deepcopy, references are replaced by references to copy of initial references. An example is worth 1000 words :)

Comment: I got this part, I just don't understand why form1 itself should be changed... even if I didn't use copy()/deepcopy(), it doesn't make too much sense for me that the FORM object is changed when I'm saving the MODEL object (the form is being saved with commit=False, which just generates an object which will then be saved)

Comment: This is because form.instance is set when the form is instanciated (django/forms/models.py line 233 in django 1.3.1) and not when you call save(). So you can call save() as many times as you want: it will always be the same model instance.